# App package does not support culture en-us specified for installation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Getting this error while uploading Addin for debugging from VS2015
"App package does not support culture en-us specified for installation"

What is the problem it was working fine before may 2017.

Comment: You must ensure that the when you want to install, that the language options match the specified supported language within the SharePoint store

Answer (score 0):

Appmenifest file had wrong CultureName="xx", change it to

`<SupportedLocale CultureName="xx-XX" />`

or remove the SupportedLocale block